# Project.property file missing 

Tags: eclipse, android

Can someone help fix this: I'm opening my project in eclipse, i'm getting the following error

> Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

I've already tried using Android Tools>Fix Project Properties option. Didn't work!

I went through some of the solutions around and none really answered my query. Most of them suggest that it's some kinda error importing the project but i never removed it from my workspace.
I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the error i'm getting, but just this morning my comp wouldn't start up and windows restored itself to a really, really old state (i'm guessing to a time before I had the sdk's and stuff). I had to reinstall the sdk's and i did, but the error still didn't go away.

Answer (score 0):

try clean your project. if does not work, then you create another project but you select the option create project from existing source.

Comment: thanks .. i tried cleaning it up and creating another project from an existing source . still didn't work ... so i created a new empty project .. copied the project.properties file to the other project and eclipse automatically updated the file .. so my project is up and running again ! ..